# Rails and Heroku : ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8) in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

I have this error :

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
2017-02-07T14:20:10.477043+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:15:in `show'
```

in heroku logs in production. And the browser doesn't load the page, I have the message "something went wrong", and I don't understand where is the problem.

It happened on a page called school, which display the 3 nearest premium school thanks to geocoder. But it doesn't happened on all the schools page, so it's really weird. In the admin, I can see that the schools with problem have this entry :

```
- !ruby/hash:BSON::Document
  raw_data: !binary |-
```

and schools without problem :

```
- !ruby/object:BSON::ObjectId
  raw_data: !binary |-
```

Here is the task that I launch for geocode premium school and insert in mongo db :

```
namespace :geocodeschool do

  desc "Show premium school near non-premium school and update them"

  task :schgc => :environment do

      @schools = School.all

      def premium_school_aside(school)
        radius = 50
        @schools_a = School.near(school.coordinates.reverse, radius, units: :km)
        @schools_premium = @schools_a.premium_school.limit(3)
      end

      @schools.each do |school|
        premium_school_aside(school)
        puts "// -------------- //"
        puts "AUTO-ÉCOLE : #{school.title}"
        puts "// -------------- //"
        puts "les auto-écoles premiums près de #{school.title} : #{@schools_premium.count}"
        puts "-------"
          if school.school_premium_asides.blank?
              school.push(school_premium_asides: @schools_premium.map(&:id))
          else
            school.update_attributes(school_premium_asides: @schools_premium.map(&:id))
          end
        puts "ICI POUR VOIR : #{@schools_premium.map(&:title)}"
        school.save
    end

  end

end
```

(the field where I insert data is an Array)

And here is the line which is mentionned in the error message :

```
@schools_premium_aside = School.where(:id.in => @school.school_premium_asides)
```

I'm not sure that is due to the french text and accent, because many schools have accents and special characters and they are well displaying ..

Someone could help me to understand where is the problem ? (sorry for the english, I'm French)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are working in French, so I expect your user data includes the French names of schools, some of which have accented characters. If these are not encoded as UTF-8 in the DB then you will get this error when trying to display them. This would explain why one page has problems and another doesn't.

You may need to check the encoding that MongoDB is using and tell Rails to expect that encoding e.g. by putting the following in `environment.rb`

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm not sure, but do you think that I could do this :  `@schools_premium_aside = School.where(:id.in => @school.school_premium_asides).encode('utf-8')`in the controller instead of changing the `environment.rb` ?

Comment: I forgot to precise : some schools with french name, accent ... are working well